# Is there an official documentation standard for Scheme?

Tags: documentation, scheme, javadoc, doc, r5rs

Java has javadoc. Python has docstrings. But what about Scheme?

I'm wondering if there is any standard way of commenting Scheme programs that allows for later creation of documentation.

It's being hard to find it on Google because "Scheme" means a lot of thing. Thank you!

Note that I'm not asking for recommendations of Scheme documentation tools; I merely wish to know if a standard format for documenting Scheme exists as it does in other languages.

Comment: Well, you could try [SchemeDoc](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/schemedoc/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [SchemeDoc](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/schemedoc/) is what you're looking for. From the linked site:

> SchemeDoc is a tool for extraction of interface documentation (API documentation) from a Scheme source file. As such, SchemeDoc is a member of the familiy of interface documentation extraction tools, such as JavaDoc and Doxygen. The documentation extracted by SchemeDoc is presented as HTML files with use of CSS stylesheets. SchemeDoc is implemented in Scheme with use of the LAML libraries

Also you might find interesting [this thread](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2011-April/thread.html#45028) in Racket's mailing list.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli the powers that be (rightly) reopened this question, so I added my comment as an answer :)